# Jssor Full Width Slider, Resizing Issue

Tags: slider, width, jssor

I just implemented the Jssor full width slider and it's beautiful. But I am having a few issues. I'm attempting to get the slider to be able to resize horizontally, without changing the height. Something like [Custom Ink](http://www.customink.com) does. However, when you resize the browser window, it tends to make the slider height larger, which then overlaps my menu underneath it. The only solution I could think of was setting a max-height for the container and the slides, but it still isn't working right. Now when I resize, it cuts off the slider, because the container doesn't expand.

Can any of you help me so the slider can expand horizontally but not vertically? I've looked at all the questions already asked about Jssor, but couldn't manage to get any of the code snippets to work the way I want. Thanks!

My slider is live at [swagrobot.com](http://www.swagrobot.com)

Answer (score 0):

Please replace 'height: 400px !important;' with 'height: 400px;', remove responsive code, place your slider in a wrapper.

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

        var _CaptionTransitions = [];
        _CaptionTransitions["L"] = { $Duration: 900, x: 0.6, $Easing: { $Left: $Jease$.$InOutSine }, $Opacity: 2 };
        _CaptionTransitions["R"] = { $Duration: 900, x: -0.6, $Easing: { $Left: $Jease$.$InOutSine }, $Opacity: 2 };
        _CaptionTransitions["T"] = { $Duration: 900, y: 0.6, $Easing: { $Top: $Jease$.$InOutSine }, $Opacity: 2 };
        _CaptionTransitions["B"] = { $Duration: 900, y: -0.6, $Easing: { $Top: $Jease$.$InOutSine }, $Opacity: 2 };
        _CaptionTransitions["ZMF|10"] = { $Duration: 900, $Zoom: 11, $Easing: { $Zoom: $Jease$.$OutQuad, $Opacity: $Jease$.$Linear }, $Opacity: 2 };
        _CaptionTransitions["RTT|10"] = { $Duration: 900, $Zoom: 11, $Rotate: 1, $Easing: { $Zoom: $Jease$.$OutQuad, $Opacity: $Jease$.$Linear, $Rotate: $Jease$.$InExpo }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 0.8} };
        _CaptionTransitions["RTT|2"] = { $Duration: 900, $Zoom: 3, $Rotate: 1, $Easing: { $Zoom: $Jease$.$InQuad, $Opacity: $Jease$.$Linear, $Rotate: $Jease$.$InQuad }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 0.5} };
        _CaptionTransitions["RTTL|BR"] = { $Duration: 900, x: -0.6, y: -0.6, $Zoom: 11, $Rotate: 1, $Easing: { $Left: $Jease$.$InCubic, $Top: $Jease$.$InCubic, $Zoom: $Jease$.$InCubic, $Opacity: $Jease$.$Linear, $Rotate: $Jease$.$InCubic }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 0.8} };
        _CaptionTransitions["CLIP|LR"] = { $Duration: 900, $Clip: 15, $Easing: { $Clip: $Jease$.$InOutCubic }, $Opacity: 2 };
        _CaptionTransitions["MCLIP|L"] = { $Duration: 900, $Clip: 1, $Move: true, $Easing: { $Clip: $Jease$.$InOutCubic} };
        _CaptionTransitions["MCLIP|R"] = { $Duration: 900, $Clip: 2, $Move: true, $Easing: { $Clip: $Jease$.$InOutCubic} };

        var options = {
            $FillMode: 2,                                       //[Optional] The way to fill image in slide, 0 stretch, 1 contain (keep aspect ratio and put all inside slide), 2 cover (keep aspect ratio and cover whole slide), 4 actual size, 5 contain for large image, actual size for small image, default value is 0
            $AutoPlay: true,                                    //[Optional] Whether to auto play, to enable slideshow, this option must be set to true, default value is false
            $AutoPlayInterval: 6000,                            //[Optional] Interval (in milliseconds) to go for next slide since the previous stopped if the slider is auto playing, default value is 3000
            $PauseOnHover: 1,                                   //[Optional] Whether to pause when mouse over if a slider is auto playing, 0 no pause, 1 pause for desktop, 2 pause for touch device, 3 pause for desktop and touch device, 4 freeze for desktop, 8 freeze for touch device, 12 freeze for desktop and touch device, default value is 1

            $ArrowKeyNavigation: true,                          //[Optional] Allows keyboard (arrow key) navigation or not, default value is false
            $SlideEasing: $Jease$.$OutQuint,          //[Optional] Specifies easing for right to left animation, default value is $Jease$.$OutQuad
            $SlideDuration: 800,                               //[Optional] Specifies default duration (swipe) for slide in milliseconds, default value is 500
            $MinDragOffsetToSlide: 20,                          //[Optional] Minimum drag offset to trigger slide , default value is 20
            //$SlideWidth: 600,                                 //[Optional] Width of every slide in pixels, default value is width of 'slides' container
            //$SlideHeight: 300,                                //[Optional] Height of every slide in pixels, default value is height of 'slides' container
            $SlideSpacing: 0,                                   //[Optional] Space between each slide in pixels, default value is 0
            $Cols: 1,                                  //[Optional] Number of pieces to display (the slideshow would be disabled if the value is set to greater than 1), the default value is 1
            $Align: 0,                                //[Optional] The offset position to park slide (this options applys only when slideshow disabled), default value is 0.
            $UISearchMode: 1,                                   //[Optional] The way (0 parellel, 1 recursive, default value is 1) to search UI components (slides container, loading screen, navigator container, arrow navigator container, thumbnail navigator container etc).
            $PlayOrientation: 1,                                //[Optional] Orientation to play slide (for auto play, navigation), 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 5 horizental reverse, 6 vertical reverse, default value is 1
            $DragOrientation: 1,                                //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $DisplayPieces is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)

            $CaptionSliderOptions: {                            //[Optional] Options which specifies how to animate caption
                $Class: $JssorCaptionSlider$,                   //[Required] Class to create instance to animate caption
                $CaptionTransitions: _CaptionTransitions,       //[Required] An array of caption transitions to play caption, see caption transition section at jssor slideshow transition builder
                $PlayInMode: 1,                                 //[Optional] 0 None (no play), 1 Chain (goes after main slide), 3 Chain Flatten (goes after main slide and flatten all caption animations), default value is 1
                $PlayOutMode: 3                                 //[Optional] 0 None (no play), 1 Chain (goes before main slide), 3 Chain Flatten (goes before main slide and flatten all caption animations), default value is 1
            },

            $BulletNavigatorOptions: {                          //[Optional] Options to specify and enable navigator or not
                $Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$,                 //[Required] Class to create navigator instance
                $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                $Steps: 1,                                      //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
                $Rows: 1,                                      //[Optional] Specify lanes to arrange items, default value is 1
                $SpacingX: 8,                                   //[Optional] Horizontal space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
                $SpacingY: 8,                                   //[Optional] Vertical space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
                $Orientation: 1                                 //[Optional] The orientation of the navigator, 1 horizontal, 2 vertical, default value is 1
            },

            $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {                           //[Optional] Options to specify and enable arrow navigator or not
                $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,                  //[Requried] Class to create arrow navigator instance
                $ChanceToShow: 1,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                $Steps: 1                                       //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
            }
        };

        var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);
    });

</script>

<div style="position: relative; width: 100%; background-color: #003399; overflow: hidden;">
    <div style="position: relative; left: 50%; width: 5000px; text-align: center; margin-left: -2500px;">
        <div id="slider1_container" style="position: absolute; margin: 0 auto; top: 349px; left: 0px; width: 1300px; height: 400px; overflow: hidden; z-index: 999;">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I think we're moving in the right direction. Right now I have removed the !important tags from the height. I attempted to add the two lines of code for the wrapper, but that may it disappear completely...  There was just a blank space on the page. I wasn't sure if I was putting the close </divs> in the right spot? Should that be after the slider1_container, the slides container, or at the end? I tried moving them around to no luck. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Please place your slider container (<div id="slider1_container"...) inside the 2 divs.

Comment: Also is there a way to keep the arrows/text/captions responsive and not the pictures? That way if someone has a very narrow browser, they will still see the text on the images?

Comment: Jssor, I did that, and it adds a dark grey portion in my header above my banner and logo, but does not display anything on the page. I have my code in the header because it is the only way the image can be fullwidth, if I enter the code as a code block in squarespace as a page element, it's not edge to edge, there's margins on the side. Any ideas?Thank you!

Comment: Here's the slider with your changes: http://www.swagrobot.com/slider-1 -- see what I mean?

Comment: please check your 'slider1_container' element, replace 'top: 349px;' with 'top: 0px;', replace 'position: absolute;' with 'position: relative;'

Comment: Awesome! Almost there, I'm now getting the blue background, which is good. Once I replaced the position and top elements, the slider appears but is positioned above the site content (since the tag is in the header), that's why I was trying to use the absolute position to push it down. The only other issue, is on mobile, it's too wide and cut off. It's almost there, if you could please help me with these last couple things I would be so grateful! Thank you! http://www.swagrobot.com/slider-1

Comment: Re 1: please move your slider under <header id="header" ... element. Re 2: please add <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"> in <head> element.